# What is the difference between softmax and log-softmax?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, softmax

The difference between these two functions that has been described in this pytorch post: [What is the difference between log_softmax and softmax?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-log-softmax-and-softmax/11801)
 is: `exp(x_i) / exp(x).sum()`
and log softmax is: `log(exp(x_i) / exp(x).sum())`.

But for the Pytorch code below why am I getting different output:

```
>>> it = autograd.Variable(torch.FloatTensor([0.6229,0.3771]))
>>> op = autograd.Variable(torch.LongTensor([0]))
>>> m  = nn.Softmax()
>>> log = nn.LogSoftmax()
>>> m(it)
Variable containing:
`0.5611  0.4389`
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x2]
>>>log(it)
Variable containing:
-0.5778 -0.8236
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x2]
```

However, the value log(0.5611) is -0.25095973129 and log(0.4389) is -0.35763441915

Why is there such discrepancy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `torch.log` provides the natural logarithm of the input, so the output of PyTorch is correct:

```
ln([0.5611,0.4389])=[-0.5778,-0.8236]
```

Your last results are obtained using the logarithm with base 10.

Answer (score 2):

Not just by default but always [`torch.log`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.log) is natural log.
While [`torch.log10`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.log10) is base 10 log.